# getElementsByClassName from scratch with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

My code doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  let result = [];
  let child = document.body.childNodes;
  function nodeRecusion(node) {
    for (let i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
      let current = node[i];
      if (current.classList.contains(className)) {
      result.push(node[i]);
      }
      if (current.childNodes.length) {
      nodeRecusion(current);
      }
    }
  }
  nodeRecusion(child);
  return result;
};
```

The error I'm getting is 'cannot read property `.contains` of `undefined`'. I don't understand the issue though. Is it not receiving child properly or is the problem with how I'm trying to call it recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) attribute is available for [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) class and not for [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) interface.

You can use `document.body.children` instead.

```js
var getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
  let result = [];
  let child = document.body.children;

  function nodeRecusion(node) {
    for (let i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
      let current = node[i];
      if (current.classList.contains(className)) {
        result.push(node[i]);
      }
      if (current.children.length) {
        nodeRecusion(current);
      }
    }
  }
  
  nodeRecusion(child);
  return result;
};

console.log(getElementsByClassName('ele'));
```

```html
<p class='ele'></p>
<span class='ele'></span>
<span class='stack'></span>
```

Comment: node is just the name of the argument I'm passing into the function. It could be called `element` or any other name

Comment: @Marcus [`.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) returns a live `NodeList`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm supposed to go about solving the problem using `document.body, element.classList,` and `element.childNodes`. How would I go about accessing the elements within `document.body` if not by using `document.body.childNodes`?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it in the third line

```
let child = document.body.children;
```